# How to populate database table with names that could be in different formats?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, ms-access

In `Table1` there is an `Input` column which is being filled with user-inputted customer names, either in `<Surname>, <First Name>` format or `<First Name> <Surname>` format.  There is also a `CustomerNo` column.

In table `Customers` there are `Surname` and `FirstName` columns filled with customer names.  There is also an auto-generated `CustomerNo` column for each customer.

What query will populate `Table1.CustomerNo` with the correct `CustomerNo` from `Customers` based on `Table1.Input`, catering for both possible formats of `Input`?

Comment: I am trying to target both SqlServer and Access-MDB, so ANSI-SQL would be fine.

Comment: @HansUp: I have removed this requirement from my question.

Comment: Does that mean the `Input` value will now contain complete `FirstName` and `Surname` values rather than fragments of each?

Comment: @HansUp: yes, it must be an exact match

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hacky way of splitting the names into components (SQL-Server dialect):

```
create table InputNames (InputName nvarchar(50));

insert into InputNames (InputName) values ('Smith, John');
insert into InputNames (InputName) values ('Mary Smith');
insert into InputNames (InputName) values ('Mark Jones');
insert into InputNames (InputName) values ('White, Barry');
insert into InputNames (InputName) values ('Damien Drybread, Esquire');

select 
InputName, 
case when charindex(',', inputname, 1) = 0 then 
substring (inputname, 1, charindex (' ', inputname, 1) - 1) 
else 
substring (inputname, charindex (',', inputname, 1) + 2, 99) 
end
as firstname,
case when charindex(',', inputname, 1) = 0 then 
substring (inputname, charindex (' ', inputname, 1) + 1, 99) 
else 
substring (inputname, 1, charindex (',', inputname, 1) - 1) 
end
as lastname

from inputnames
```

Here's the output

```
InputName   firstname   lastname
Smith, John John    Smith
Mary Smith  Mary    Smith
Mark Jones  Mark    Jones
White, Barry    Barry   White
Damien Drybread, Esquire    Esquire Damien Drybread
```

... and you can see that there are corner cases that you would need to cater for if your names can have a comma in them that is not the separator between the first and last names.

Similar approach would work for MS Access, but you will have to use "Iif" instead of case statement, and "InStr" instead of charindex.

Comment: @Remou Useful and Comprehensive - perhaps you should post as an answer? If the OP is using MS Access as a front end, that would be a good solution for either an Access or SQL-Server back end.

Comment: I am afraid it would not sit right with me to post the whole code under my name, even with proper references, and anything less than the whole code would not be helpful.